# Split CSV into multiple CSVs with a header Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am using this code to split a CSV into multiple smaller csv files but it is not populating the header after creating the first CSV file.

```
    $file = "C:\temp\WebEx2\allmbx.csv"
    $header = Get-Content $file -First 1
    $i=0; Get-Content $file -ReadCount 4500 | 
    %{$i++; if($i-gt 1){$header | 
    Set-Content C:\temp\WebEx2\MBX-$i.csv;} $_ | 
    Add-Content C:\temp\WebEx.\MBX-$i.csv}
```

Comment: use `Import-CSV` for better results and easier to work with objects

Comment: as @AbrahamZinala pointed out, the CSV cmdlets are made for this sort of thing. use `Import-Csv` to bring things in as objects, a counter to set the batch size, and `Export-Csv` to send each batch out.